# Field connect_timeout is missing in name service_envoyproxy_io

Tags: envoyproxy

on runnning envoy proxy using this command
`envoy -c envoy-demo.yaml`

i got this error

```
[critical][main] [external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:113] error initializing configuration 'envoy-demo.yaml': Field 'connect_timeout' is missing in: name: "service_envoyproxy_io"
```

http://localhost:10000/  is not opening in browser

Answer (score 5):

added connect_timeout under clusters in envoy-demo.yaml

e.g.

```
  clusters:
  - name: service_envoyproxy_io
    type: LOGICAL_DNS
    connect_timeout: 5s
```